# non-consecutive insertion in vectors

Tags: c++, vector

Is it possible to inset values in a std::vector in an non-consecutive manner like,

```
std::vector<int> Myvector;
//Myvector[0] = 123;
//Myvecotr[2] = 456;
//Myvector[5] = 789;
```

Comment: What value do you want the elements between those to have?

Comment: You probably require a `std::map<int,int>` instead of vector.

Comment: In between the elements I am planning to insert null value or zero or anything.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked: what for? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your code uses an index for an element that does not yet exist. Or in other words, if your index exceeds (>=) `vector::size()` then you are accessing a non existent element. Alas you end up in undefined-behaviour.

```
std::vector<int> Myvector;
Myvector[0] = 123; // boom  Myvector[0] was never created
```

So you need to add those elements

```
// the boring way
Myvector.push_back(0);
Myvector.push_back(0);
Myvector.push_back(0);
Myvector.push_back(0);
Myvector[0] = 123; // set element 0 to 123
Myvector[2] = 456; // set element 2 to 456
```

Or as stated in other answers you set the size (which I'd prefer):

```
Myvector.resize(5);
```

Or state the size from begin on:

```
std::vector<int> Myvector(5); // 5 elements, all with the value of the default c'tor
```

Answer (score 6):

Sort of. You can't really *insert* this way, but you can set the size, and only set values for those you care about.

If you really want it to be sparse (e.g., in your example Myvector[1], [3], [4] wouldn't exist at all), then no. For something like that, you could use an `std::map<int, int>` instead of a vector.

Comment: Or maybe an `std::unordered_map<int, int>`, if you can use C++11, what may perform better, but won't give you values in key sequence if you iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the size in the beginning then you can do something like this

```
vector<int> iVec(5);
iVec[0] = 0;
iVec[2] = 2;
iVec[4] = 4;
```